# How to scrape past a "Show More" button using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I've seen a number of questions on this topic, but it seems like what really matters is how the "show more" button functions, and I'm not fluent enough to figure that out.

I'm trying to scrape [this page](https://www.llbean.com/llb/shop/630?page=womens-footwear&csp=f&bc=474&gnrefine=1*BRAND*L.L.Bean&sort_field=relevance&start=1&viewCount=48&nav=gnro2-hp&newPla=1), but I want to get all results and not just the ones above the "show more" button at the bottom. My code below already works fine for the results above the button.

```
import requests as re
import bs4
import pandas as pd


url = 'https://www.llbean.com/llb/shop/630?page=womens-footwear&csp=f&bc=474&gnrefine=1*BRAND*L.L.Bean&sort_field=relevance&start=1&viewCount=48&nav=gnro2-hp&newPla=1'

result = re.get(url)

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(result.text, 'lxml')

products = soup.find_all('li', class_='ProductThumbnail_container')

product_data = {'Image':[], 'Style Name':[], 'Style Type':[], 'Color Offering':[], 'Price Point':[], 'Sale Price Point':[],
'Description':[], '"Why we love it" LLBEAN SPECIFIC':[], 'F&B/construction':[], 'Reviews Rating':[], 'Number of Reviews':[],
'Review Notes':[], 'Merch Notes':[], 'Link':[]}

for i in products:
    product_image = i.find('img')
    product_name = i.find('a', class_='ProductThumbnail_name Anchor_not-underlined Anchor_anchor')
    product_colors = i.find('div', class_='ProductThumbnail_color-count')
    product_price = i.find('span', class_='')
    product_sales_price = i.find('span', class_='sale')
    product_rating = i.find('span', itemprop='ratingValue')
    product_number_of_reviews = i.find('a', class_='Rating_count Anchor_anchor')
    product_link = i.find('a', class_='ProductThumbnail_product')
    product_data['Image'].append(product_image.attrs['src'])
    product_data['Style Name'].append(product_name.string)
    product_data['Style Type'].append('')
    try:
        product_data['Color Offering'].append(product_colors.string.split('"')[1])
    except:
        product_data['Color Offering'].append('')
    try:
        product_data['Price Point'].append(product_price.string)
    except:
        product_data['Price Point'].append('')
    try:
        product_data['Sale Price Point'].append(product_sales_price.string)
    except:
        product_data['Sale Price Point'].append('')
    product_data['Description'].append('')
    product_data['"Why we love it" LLBEAN SPECIFIC'].append('')
    product_data['F&B/construction'].append('')
    try:
        product_data['Reviews Rating'].append(product_rating.string)
    except:
        product_data['Reviews Rating'].append('')
    try:
        product_data['Number of Reviews'].append(product_number_of_reviews.string)
    except:
        product_data['Number of Reviews'].append('')
    product_data['Review Notes'].append('')
    product_data['Merch Notes'].append('')
    product_data['Link'].append(product_link.attrs['href'])

df = pd.DataFrame(product_data)

df.to_csv('llbean_womens.csv')
```

Comment: Did you ensure that the products data after the show more button are in the page source?

Comment: @RadoTheProgrammer If I right click one and click "inspect," I can see the html?

Comment: Could not reproduce the issue of a "Show More" button, the site works with infinite scroll for me.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Inspect > Network > xhr and scroll to end of the page. As you can see new contents added to list of xhr's. Query parameters in that url is like:

> ?start=48&sz=12&format=page-element

**start=48** indicates to product with 48'th index and **sz=12** is number of product for each load.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example how you can use Ajax API to load all pages:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

api_url = "https://global.llbean.com/shop/Womens-Footwear/630"
params = {"start": "0", "sz": "12", "format": "page-element"}


for start in range(0, 3):  # <-- increase number of pages here
    params["start"] = start * 12

    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(api_url, params=params).content, "html.parser")

    # get names for an example:
    for name in soup.select(".product-name"):
        print(name.get_text(strip=True))

    # ... get other info from the soup
```

Prints:

```
Women's Wicked Good Moccasins
Adults' Katahdin Hiker Socks
Women's Boothbay Slide Sandals
Adults' Merino Wool Ragg Socks, 10" Two-Pack
Adults' Wicked Cozy Socks
Women's Wellie Sport Rubber Chelsea Boots
Women's Wicked Good Shearling-Lined Slides
Women's Storm Chaser Boots 4, Lace-Up with Arctic Grip
Women's Storm Chaser 4 Slip-Ons with Arctic Grip
Women's Bean Boots, Rubber Moc
Women's Daybreak Scuffs, Motif
Adults' Wicked Soft Cotton Socks
Women's Bean Boots, 7" Fleece-Lined Insulated Front-Zip
Women's Wicked Good Slippers, Venetian
Adults' Cresta Wool Midweight Hiking Socks, Quarter-Crew
Women's Rangeley Insulated Pac Boots, Ankle
Women's Wicked Good Camp Moccasins
Women's Wicked Good Clogs

...and so on.
```